# Displaying flask json data in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, json, flask, pythonanywhere

I have a simple flask app running, that posts some data after a user input. At the moment, it displays this data in a json.dump dictionary, but I am trying to get it to display as follows:

```
Name:     yyy
Shack:    yyy
Status:   yyy
Payments: vvv
```

I've seen some questions relating to jsonify and other json methods, but I can't seem to get them to work. 
Code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response, render_template
import json
import sys
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['DEBUG'] = True

path = '/home/username/ishack/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

client_db = np.genfromtxt('/home/username/ishack/client_db.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True)



@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template('form_page.html')


@app.route('/address', methods=['POST'])
def display_info():
    address = request.form['address']
    ind = np.where(client_db['Shack'] == address)[0]
    res = {'Name': client_db[ind]['Name'][0],
            'Shack': client_db[ind]['Shack'][0],
            'Status': client_db[ind]['Status'][0],
            'Payments': client_db[ind]['Payments'][0]}
    return Response(json.dumps(res), mimetype='application/json')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the response to render a page with the desired formatting. You cannot stylize a plain JSON response.

```
@app.route('/address', methods=['POST'])
def display_info():
    address = request.form['address']
    ind = np.where(client_db['Shack'] == address)[0]
    res = {'Name': client_db[ind]['Name'][0],
            'Shack': client_db[ind]['Shack'][0],
            'Status': client_db[ind]['Status'][0],
            'Payments': client_db[ind]['Payments'][0]}
    return render_template("address_page.html", address=res)
```

**address_page.html**:

```
<table>
{% for key,value in address.items() %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{key}}:</td><td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Nice one! Is there any way to sort the table as described in the question? ('Name:' at the top)

Comment: @wazzahenry Yes. Instead of passing a dictionary, you can pass an ordered list of dictionary. You should take a look at Jinja templating docs to explore various such options :)